# Is there any shortcut for highlighting a text

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts, highlighting

Here by highlighting, I mean `this`. Is there any keyboard shortcut for this. I didn't find any info about this anywhere. I know I can do this by placing them inside two sqiggle.
A shortcut would be helpful.

Comment: You can see the keyboard shortcuts in the tooltips in the editor: just hover with the mouse over the tool, and knowledge will come your way ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> shortcut to get either code blocks or code spans.

When you select a portion of a single line of text, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> surrounds the selected text with backticks to give you `this` (A code span).

When you select an entire line of text or across multiple lines of text, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> indents each selected line(s) by four spaces to give you

```
this
```

(A code block).